# Transition for text box to top of page not working properly for Safari and Chrome on IOS

Tags: javascript, ios, css, google-chrome, safari

There is text box at the bottom of page. Whenever it is focused it should be transitioned to the top of page. This is because I want to show suggestions to user when typing. This implementation is working for PC and for android devices. While for IOS devices when the visual keypad is displayed the Text box goes out of view port but appears again when I press 'done'.

Following is the CSS I am using:

```
#searchSection {
position: relative;
/*-webkit-overflow-scrolling: auto;*/
transition: all 0.5s;
-webkit-transition: all 0.5s; /*safari*/
-webkit-transition-delay: 0;
-moz-transition: all 0.5s;
-o-transition: all 0.5s;}

#searchSection .focused {
position: fixed;
top: 0;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
height: 100%;
background: #e8e8e8;
width: 100%;
z-index: 1000;
/*-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;*/}
```

Following is the JS which modifies the class name:

```
goog.events.listen(
        searchInput,
        goog.events.EventType.FOCUS, function () {
            goog.dom.classlist.add(searchSection, 'focused');
        }
    );
```

Is there any solution/workaround to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my experience Safari on iOS (Chrome is using the same engine there) has problems with inputs in containers that have `position: fixed`.

I helped myself by using `position: absolute` instead and scrolling to the input element before giving it focus.

Comment: But `position: absolute` will take div out of viewport on scrolling.

Comment: I placed the input at the very top of the page with `position: absolute; top: 0;`, then scrolled the page to the top. I couldn't find another way that worked for Safari.

Comment: This is workaround and not solution to the problem but definitely helpful. How can I do it for IOS devices only and not for other devices?